# i bulid stored procedure in MySql server but doesn't work !

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

how to bulid  a stored procedure in MySql server .
i wrote the stored procedure outside in note but i don't know how to apply this stored procedure in the server that i am doing the testin .
to be clear i download wampSever which includes Mysql ,then i created my tables. but again i don't know the steps that i have to take in orded to use the stored procedure.

my stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE findHorse
@horseName varchar(15) AS SELECT * FROM horse
WHERE horseName =@horseName
```

i know that if i wante to execute it i use

```
exec findHorse
```

all what i need are :
1. how to create it in mySql. //steps
2.where should i put  exec findHorse in order to execute it //steps

Comment: also the same idea with triggers

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you execute a stored procedure by 'calling' it:

```
CALL DoStuff(@Param1);
```

You create one as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoStuff()
BEGIN
   SELECT Column1
   FROM MyTable;
END;
```

[This might help](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm)

Comment: how can i convert my pice to your syntax help please ;because i find the syntax i followed in the internet but acutly i don't know if it for my sql .so what my syntax that used ? is it for oracl

Comment: when i tried it error happens the message says :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 8

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `findHorse` (IN `inFindHorse` CHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM `horse` WHERE `horse`.`horseName` = `inFindHorse`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And as Randy noted, the correct way to call this procedure is:

```
CALL findHorse('Flicka');
```